# Consuming WCF soap service from a Web Api service

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble finding examples of using a Web Api REST service to consume a WCF soap based service. I have my Web Api set up with the service references to the other service, but when I try to create an instance of the WCF service, my intellisense doesn't see the WCF service references. I'd appreciate any insight on this topic.

Comment: Does a Rebuild help? Typically, service references are located in a different namespace. Can this be the issue?

Comment: Did a rebuild, and had the soap service running, neither helped. I had an idea to just reference the .dll of the soap service and make the REST service a wrapper of sorts.

Comment: If you can move the functionality from the WCF service to another DLL (or reference the WCF dll directly), it's way better. Saves time because you have one request less.

Comment: I wonder if there will be any issue with the soap service .dll calling the database associated with that project. Should I set the connection string in the REST service web.config?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to set the connection string in the REST config as well. Also the box hosting the REST service needs to be able to reach the db server. Depends on your infrastructure

Comment: @Rex_C - did you get anywere with this - I am also trying to consume and external SOAP based service that has a WSDL into a WEB API that I can then use RESTfully

Comment: @KOL - Unfortunately, the project got put on the back burner, so I haven't fiddled with it lately.

Comment: @Rex_C - no worries - managed to get it working :)